# with `flex-basis = 0` how does a flex sub-container decide what with it has

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: hotpink;
}

.flex-box {
    display: flex;
    background-color: gray;
}

.flex-box .box-1 {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.flex-box .box-2 {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="flex-box">
        <div class="box-1">
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor si?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-2">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

I have a `main` that has flex with `flex-direction: column` and with `align-items: center` and it has a div inside it with flex as well. I have a div
`div.box-2`, inside the inner flex box with a width of `100px`. `flex-basis` is 0 on both the children of the inner flex box's children.

Now the inner flex box gets a computed width of `256.217px`. my question is where does this number come from. box-1 gets a computer width value of `128.1px` and box-2 gets `128.12px`.

with a `flex-basis` of 0 and `flex-grow` of 1. the boxes can grow from their original height but where does get this `128px` value come from

[image]

if I remove the `width: 100px` from box-2
then now box-1 has a `width` of `301.867px` and box-2
has `301.883px` to make a combined parent container width of `603.75px`. **But** again where are these values coming from.

[image]

Comment: Depends on the content of the item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step by step illustration to understand the logic:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: hotpink;
  margin:5px;
}

.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
}
.flex-box .box-1 {
  /*flex: 1 1 0;*/
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.flex-box .box-2 {
  /*flex: 1 1 0
  width: 100px; */
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
We apply nothing and each element will take the width of its content without line break
<main>
  <div class="flex-box">
    <div class="box-1">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor si?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
We make the second item width:100px. it will shrink to that width and everything will remain centred
<main>
  <div class="flex-box">
    <div class="box-1">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor si?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2" style="width:100px">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
Now the width of flex-box we have above will be the reference for the flex calculation and when we apply flex: 1 1 0 to both, then each one will get half that width 

<main>
  <div class="flex-box">
    <div class="box-1" style="flex:1 1 0">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor si?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2" style="width:100px;flex:1 1 0">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

As you can see, the default of the first item + 100px of the second is the total width used and divided between both items.

Same logic happen in your second case but without the 100px:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: hotpink;
  margin:5px;
}

.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
}
.flex-box .box-1 {
  /*flex: 1 1 0;*/
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.flex-box .box-2 {
  /*flex: 1 1 0
  width: 100px; */
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
We apply nothing and each element will take the width of its content without line break
<main>
  <div class="flex-box">
    <div class="box-1">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor si?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
Now the width of flex-box we have above will be the reference for the flex calculation and when we apply flex: 1 1 0 to both, then each one will get half that width 

<main>
  <div class="flex-box">
    <div class="box-1" style="flex:1 1 0">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor si?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2" style="flex:1 1 0">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: thanks for the well explained answer. are there any other rules it uses to decide the flex-box width or is it always using this methodology. what if it's not text inside the box but instead some other elements

Comment: @masonCherry all depend on your HTML structure. What I described apply to your specific case. If you change/add one rule, the whole explanation may change. This is not a methodology, it's the flexbox algorithm applied to your case.

Comment: so how can I know that flexbox algorithm to use for the specific case. therefore I'm asking   how I can figure out in a general case what flex will do to compute it's width.

Comment: @masonCherry you read the detailed algorithm written in the specification here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#layout-algorithm ... It may take you months to understand only few parts. In CSS, it's not easy to grasp the generic cases (even for the most experienced developer). We learn CSS by understanding case by case.